# Drawing line collision?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs6

I've gotten actions on a frame, what I'm trying to do is have a `hitTest` that triggers `gotoAndStop(<lose frame>)` when the shape I am drawing collides with the `touchTest`. The only issue I'm having is I cannot get the `hitTest` to register directly when the line hits it, it only registers after the next click event. The other issue I'm encountering is a hit box on the `touchTest` is many times larger than the actual image of the symbol.

```
var myshape:Shape;
myshape = new Shape();
myshape.graphics.lineStyle(5, 0xC807DE);
var alreadyDrawn:Shape;
alreadyDrawn = new Shape();

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, activateDraw);
function activateDraw(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    myshape.graphics.moveTo(mouseX,mouseY);
    addChild(myshape);

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, lineDraw);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDraw);
}

function lineDraw(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    myshape.graphics.lineTo(mouseX,mouseY);
    checkIt();
}
function stopDraw(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    alreadyDrawn.graphics.copyFrom(myshape.graphics);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, lineDraw);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDraw);
}

function checkIt()
{
    if (alreadyDrawn.hitTestObject(touchTest) == true)
    {
        trace("wall");
        myshape.graphics.clear();
        myshape.graphics.lineStyle(5, 0xC807DE);
        alreadyDrawn.graphics.clear(); // clear this too
        stopDraw(null); // stop active draw, if any
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first use `copyFrom` method in your function `lineDraw`, because `alreadyDrawn` must be drawn before it's tested !

```
function lineDraw(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    myshape.graphics.lineTo(mouseX,mouseY);
    alreadyDrawn.graphics.copyFrom(myshape.graphics);
    checkIt();
}
```

This works, but not correctly because the hitTest considers the `rectangle` containing `alreadyDrawn`. You must consider that the `point` to be tested is your `mouse`.

```
function checkIt():void
{
    if (touchTest.hitTestPoint(mouseX, mouseY, true))
    {
        trace("wall");
    }
}
```